# how to change a css value froma an ajax

Tags: php, css, ajax, curl

i'm newbie to ajax i'm goog at php and css

i have a script that download files from url using cURL

and the cURL progress is written into a txt file

i use ajax to update the progress every second

i managed to echo the result in numbers like 1%, 5%, 50%

i tried to use  Progressbar | jQuery UI but i couldn't

i have a very simple css progress bar and i want to echo the ajax value in a css value

the ajax code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    function Ajax()
    {
        var
            $http,
            $self = arguments.callee;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            } catch(e) {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
        }

        if ($http) {
            $http.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                    document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
                    setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 1000);
                }
            };
            $http.open('GET', 'loadtxt.php' + '?' + new Date().getTime(), true);
            $http.send(null);
        }

    }

</script>
```

which load the loadtxt.php

its code

```
 <?php
//
$file = "progress.txt";
$f = fopen($file, "r");
while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
print $line;
}
?>
```

which read the text file that contains the progress
i have the following css code

```
<div class="meter-value" style="background-color: #0a0; width: 40%;">
```

i want to update this value

```
width: 40%;
```

from ajax
so how to update that vallue from ajax
i use the following code to get the ajax value

```
<div id="ReloadThis">Default text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work like you expect.

When using ajax like this, you send a request to the php-file, it completes the script and return the values (if anything is echoed). Making a progress-thingy with this is not possible. This is why uploadforms displaying a progressbar usally is written in Java or Flash.

You are trying to parse the readyState, but these values only represent if the ajax-call is completed, failed or pendling.

You can google around and find some examples of how to do this, but it is MUCH more difficult than having a simple loading-gif displaying while the ajax-script is running.

EDIT: Making this work would require you to for example split the script up in chunks and echo each processed chunk out using `ob_flush` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You sould change this:

```
<div class="meter-value" style="background-color: #0a0; width: 40%;">
```

for this:

```
<div id="meter-value" style="background-color: #0a0; width: 0%;">
```

After that you should change this:

```
document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
```

for this:

```
document.getElementById('meter-value').style.width = $http.responseText + '%';
```

I think this should work.

You can learn more about styling html elements with JavaScript: [Style object - w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp)

Comment: The OP's problem here is actually that they cannot get the 'progress' in this manner at all.